# Problem regarding bacteria increase modeled by formula

Tags: functions, exponential-function

Studying "Basic Mathematics" p.358, by Serge Lang, came across this exercise.

[image]

I don't know how to start with it. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Well you need to determine two constants, $C$ and $k$.  Usually that requires two equations.  Happily they have given you two useful facts...$B(0)=10^6$ and $B(12)=2\times 10^6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

First note that $C=B(0)=10^6$.

Next, you can rewrite this equation as $\;\dfrac{B(t)}{B(0)}=\mathrm e^{kt}$, and you have to find $k$. You're given that
$$\frac{B(12)}{B(0)}=2. $$
WWhen ytou have $k$, you'll just have to solve
$$\frac{B(t)}{B(0)}=10.$$
Can you end the calculations?

Comment: Thank you. How did you come up with that ratio, i.e. $\frac{B(t)}{B(0)}$ ?

Comment: The last $\,$ one?

Comment: The first ratio.

Comment: Just because $C=B(0)$.

Comment: Very close to understanding. Reviewing your answer but cannot understand how you arrived to the last ratio. Can you explain?

Comment: Yes: if at time $t$ you arrive at $10^7=10\cdot10^6$  bacteria, the ratio is $\;\dfrac{B(t)}{B(0)}=\dfrac{10\cdot10^6}{10^6}=10$, whence the equation in $t$, $\;\mathrm e^{kt}=10$. Is it clearer?

Comment: Just understanding. So, I need to solve for $k$, i.e.
\begin{aligned}
\frac{B(12)}{B(0)} &= \frac{2*10^6}{10^6} \\
k &= \frac{log_e2}{12}
\end{aligned}

Solving for $t$,
\begin{aligned}
 B(t) &= 10^7 \\
    10^6e^{(log_e2)\frac{t}{12}} &= \frac{log_e10}{log_e2} \\
    t &= 12\left(\frac{log_e10}{log_e2}\right)
\end{aligned}
Is this the correct result ?

Comment: Yes, it is the result. Please note your $\log_e$ is just the napierian logarithm and is denoted $\ln$ (code `\ln` – usual function are coded by their name preceded by a backslash).

Answer (score 0):

Try transforming your equation by taking the logarithm of both sides. What happens if you plot $log(B)$ against $t$? That should suggest several ways to solve the problem.